# How do I compile a C program to use with my ruby gem via the C program's command line interface?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, c, ruby, rubygems

I've seen lots of guides talking about using extconf.rb and c extensions in ruby gems. I don't think that'll fit my use case, as the C program I'm trying to bundle uses files to do it's work.

Some people have suggested that I just list kdiff3 as a requirement in my gem, but I added some functionality to the code, and who knows when that'll get pushed to all the package control repos.

In summary, here is what I want to do
 - compile the C code in the repo (makefile already exists, and compiles with `./configure qt4`)
 - compile hopefully would happen on gem install

Here is my gem: https://github.com/NullVoxPopuli/kdiff3-rb
the ext/kdiff3 directory is a git subtree from https://github.com/NullVoxPopuli/kdiff3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being how I 'solved' the problem. A bit of a hack, but functional.

https://github.com/NullVoxPopuli/kdiff3-rb/blob/master/ext/kdiff3/extconf.rb

```
# Unconventional way of extconf-ing
# http://yorickpeterse.com/articles/hacking-extconf-rb/
require 'mkmf'

# Stops the installation process if one of these commands is not found in
# $PATH.
find_executable('make')
find_executable('qmake')
# create fake Makefile, courtesy of
# https://github.com/leejarvis/ruby-c-example/tree/master/ext/hello
# it's ugly, and a hack, but it continues the gem install process.
# hello.c is small and meaningless in the context if this repository.
create_makefile('hello')

# build kdiff3
# - currently has to compile with qt4
#   maybe someday, qt4 can be optional
Dir.chdir('./') do
  exec './configure qt4'
end

# fail if compiling didn't succeed
unless File.exist?('releaseQT/kdiff3')
  abort("\nERROR:  kdiff3 was not successfully compiled")
end
```